# Android JSONException: JSONArray must start with [ - and it does

Tags: android, json, arrays, byte-order-mark

Okay, I know this question has been asked before, but all the answers did not help at all. First, let me recap the problem:

I have a (PHP-generated) JSON element, the PHP code looks like this:

```
if (!headers_sent()) header('Content-type: application/json');
echo "[{\"test\":\"success\"}]";
```

No other echo, print or anything else before that, so the output really is just

```
[{"test":"success"}]
```

and nothing else. The PHP file is saved as pure UTF-8 (checked and double-checked).

Now, my Android code looks as follows:

```
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://myurl");
    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == 200) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content, "UTF-8"), 8);
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
            }
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String menuData = builder.getString();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> tempList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
boolean change = false;

try {
    JSONArray jsonMenu = new JSONArray(menuData);

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonMenu.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject;
        try {
            jsonObject = jsonMenu.getJSONObject(i);

            HashMap<String, String> menuItem = new HashMap<String, String>();
            menuItem.put("test", jsonObject.getString("test"));
            tempList.add(menuItem);
            change = true;

        } catch (JSONException e) {
        }
    }

} catch (JSONException e) {
}

if(change) {
     // here comes the listview update, but never triggered anyways
}
```

And I always get the same error message:

```
04-05 21:06:31.226: W/System.err(1208): org.json.JSONException: A JSONArray text must start with '[' at character 1 of ?[{"test":"success"}]
```

This is actually the Logcat output saved to log.txt and parsed here, and then all of the sudden there is this question mark. All attempts to trim or format the String before parsing it to the JSONArray have failed. I have absolutely no clue anymore what else to do. In Logcat in Eclipse itself there is no question mark by the way...

Added Log.e output to the catch statements, the error output is exactly the same. Screenshot here:

[image: Error Message in LogCat]

Comment: wherever you have `catch (JSONException e) { ... }`  make it `catch (JSONException e) { Log.e("json error", e); }`  then please post the error you see in logcat as an edit to your question.

Comment: There's an extra character in front of your JSON, probably being generated on the PHP side.

Comment: @Perception: That's why I posted the PHP code as well. Just for the sake of it, I created a new test.php, UTF8 encoded, only containing the JSON bit - still not working.

Comment: @forgivegod: Added, it's just the same error message. Also put in a screenshot.

Comment: Are you able to hit the URL from a browser? If so check the source, maybe there is something else in the output? Also try printing your builder string first.

Comment: Yep, looks completely fine from the browser. And yeah, I tried everything (printing with log and toast, checking the string in debug mode) - the string looks fine. The only hint that something is wrong with this is the question mark that appears if I save the Logcat output in Eclipse. I'm really completely lost here.

Comment: By the way, if I put the same string manually in `menuData` it works. So it happens somewhere in the process of retrieving the JSON from the browser. I've tried several ways, HttpGet/HttpPost, several tutorials on JSON+Android... nothing.

Comment: Try dumping the bytes from `menuData` and seeing what you get as the first character.

Comment: Thanks for editing the image, Perception! :-)

Comment: @RaghavSood: Not sure if this helps, but the first byte is -17. Followed by -69, -65, 91... hm, how exactly do I do this to reveal more helpful information? ;-)

Comment: No one? :( Please help!

Comment: -17,-69,-65 expressed in hex is 0xEF,0xBB,0xBF which is the Byte Order Mark (BOM) for UTF-8.

Comment: Yeah, that is strange. I really don't know why there's BOM in there, I explicitly made sure in Notepad++ when saving the PHP file that it's pure UTF-8 and not UTF-8 incl. BOM. Anyways, after getting a night of sleep and approaching the problem with a clear head it's become obvious that I need to strip the first two bytes from my String and it should work (props @RaghavSood for the great idea of dumping bytes). So if anyone wants to grab a +1 for providing an answer... 1) how can I remove the first two bytes from an Android String and 2) any idea what might cause this BOM stuff at all?

Comment: In other words the BOM is probably in your original .php file before the <?php line, courtesy of your text editor. There's probably an option in your editor somewhere to remove it.

Comment: I recommend fixing it server-side, since your server is currently not sending a proper application/json response. If you really must fix it client-side then you can strip the leading 3 bytes with "byte[] buf = menuData.getBytes(); menuData = new String(Arrays.copyOfRange(buf, 3, buf.length - 3));"

Comment: Yes, problem solved. I'm gonna post this in my answer for future users who encounter the same problem, as I've seen several discussions where this was unsolved... maybe I'm not the only one that dumb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved:

Open the PHP file in Notepad++, click on Encoding => Encode in UTF-8 without BOM.

I neglected this because it shows "ANSI as UTF-8" in the status bar which sounded just wrong (I wanted pure UTF-8 and no ANSI mix). Yeah, I'm no Linux fella, so this ANSI/UTF-8 was something I never quite got to be honest, and here it trapped me again.

If someone is interested how I found the solution (credit goes to @Perception, @Raghav-Sood, and @Reuben-Scratton here):

Converted the menuData string to a byte array and found out that the first two chars are not the opening bracket that JSONArray is looking for, but two BOM chars.